# did not show messages in index page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create small chat application using php,mysql and ajax. After using ajax function messages did not show in output. but data are transfer to database.

**index page code**

```
<?php

  require('includes/core.inc.php');

  if(isset($_POST['send'])){

    if(send_msg($_POST['sender'], $_POST['message'])){
      echo 'Message sent.';
    }else{
      echo 'message faild to sent.';
    }

  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--Page title-->
    <title>chat application</title>

    <!--css stylesheet-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="input">
      <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <lable>Enter name:<input type="text" name="sender"/></lable>
        <lable>Enter message:<input type="text" name="message"/></lable><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send message"/>
      </form>
    </div><!--input-->


    <div id="messages">

    </div> <!--Messages-->

<!--JAVASCRIPT-->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/js/auto_chat.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

**chat.php**

```
<?php
  require('../../includes/database/connect.db.php');
  require('../../includes/functions/chat.func.php');

  $messages = get_msg();
  foreach($messages as $message){
    echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].' sent</strong><br/>';
    echo $message['message'].'<br/><br/>';
  }

 ?>
```

**chat functions**

```
<?php

  function get_msg(){

    $query = "SELECT Sender,Message FROM chat";

    $run = mysql_query($query);

    $messages = array();


    if($run === FALSE) {
      die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }


    while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){

      $messages[] = array('sender'=>$message['Sender'], 'message'=>$message['Message']);

    }

    return $messages;

  }

  function send_msg($sender, $message){
    if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)){
      $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
      $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);

      $query = "INSERT INTO chat VALUES (null , '{$sender}', '{$message}')";

      if($run = mysql_query($query)){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }

    }else{
      return false;
    }

  }

?>
```

***ajax part i added is this. i think here is the problem, but i can't find it.I did not use jquery and ajax before. so is there any pre conditions?***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'scripts/php/chat.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#messages').html(data);
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
```

i have database connection file. but there is no problem. if want i can post it. please help me

Comment: As you debug this, where/how specifically does it fail?  Observe the AJAX operations in your browser's debugging tools.  Are they successful?  Are the AJAX requests being made to the server at the expected intervals?  What is the server's response?

Comment: I'm using AJAX for first time. How can add ajax to browser. I'm using firefox browser. there is no error response. but messages are not display in index page. but when i send message it goes to database.

Comment: In Firefox I imagine the preferred debugging tool is still the Firebug plugin.  Add that yo Firefox and use it to examine the network requests being made by your AJAX code.  There could be errors that you're simply ignoring at this time.

Comment: In Firefox the developer tools under <F12> can be used without installing anything.

Comment: Rightclick in the browser, select the Inspect option, and then the console tab. For Ajax Requests you will have an XHR entry you can open and see what was sent and received. You can also get this info from the network tab.

Comment: how does it works? only install and run index file  or other way to run?

Comment: in console js tab here is the errors                                                    Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/chat/scripts/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js”.  index.php:27
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost/chat/scripts/js/auto_chat.js”.

Comment: is there any problem with jquery file?

Comment: i test your code, it will work fine in my loclahost

Comment: @manipal are seen messages in yor index page?

Comment: can you send me jquery file

Comment: yes, same jquery i used which u post, i just change php file path as per my location only

Comment: find the file auto_chat.js go to line 27. What does it say?

Comment: in auto_chat file did not have 27 lines. in index file 27 line is the starting of form tag

Comment: Do you have the two files in the scrip tags in place? Are they in the path they should be?

Comment: Probably off topic, but you echo some stuff before the doctype declaration, which causes the DOM tree to come out very different from what you expect. Also, quirks mode.

Comment: What I mean is that you must have the src attribute wrong in the script tags.

Comment: @juan yes it has. but there is fail to load js file .

Comment: Thanks guys now it's works... i created another j query file. then it's worked. thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put below code in `index.php` file

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('test',$conn);
  function send_msg($sender, $message){
    if(!empty($sender) && !empty($message)){
      $sender = mysql_real_escape_string($sender);
      $message = mysql_real_escape_string($message);
      $query = "INSERT INTO chat VALUES (null , '{$sender}', '{$message}')";
      if($run = mysql_query($query)){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
  if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(send_msg($_POST['sender'], $_POST['message'])){
      echo 'Message sent.';
    }else{
      echo 'message faild to sent.';
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--Page title-->
    <title>chat application</title>
    <!--css stylesheet-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="input">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <lable>Enter name:<input type="text" name="sender"/></lable>
        <lable>Enter message:<input type="text" name="message"/></lable><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="send message"/>
      </form>
    </div><!--input-->
    <div id="messages">
    </div> <!--Messages-->
  </body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'test1.php',
      success: function(data){
        $('#messages').html(data);
      }
    });
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

and create one file for ajax call `test1.php` and put below code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysql_select_db('test',$conn);
  function get_msg(){
    $query = "SELECT Sender,Message FROM chat";
    $run = mysql_query($query);
    $messages = array();

    if($run === FALSE) {
      die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
    }

    while($message = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)){
      $messages[] = array('sender'=>$message['Sender'], 'message'=>$message['Message']);
    }
    return $messages;
  }


  $messages = get_msg();
  foreach($messages as $message){
    echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].' sent</strong><br/>';
    echo $message['message'].'<br/><br/>';
  }

 ?>
```

above will work for me. no need to any other js files.

Comment: kindly change db connection as per you db settings.

Comment: thanks mahipal. problem is with j query file. i created another one tried it. it worked. thank you.